# how can I set repeating alarm every 5 second to show message

Tags: android, alarmmanager

here is my code in application class inside oncreate method: But I can't see any message from my app. Can anyone help me to do this?

```java
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
public void startAlarm() {
    manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    int interval = 5000;

    manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

And on the broadcast receiver  class I have the following code

```java
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        // For our recurring task, we'll just display a message
        Toast.makeText(arg0, "I'm running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edited answer**:

Use `setInexactRepeating()` instead of `setRepeating()`.  `setRepeating` only takes set intervals with the shortest being INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES.  `setInexactRepeating()` is the only way to set a repeating interval as short as 1000ms, or 5000ms in your case.

Change:

```
 manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
```

to

```
 manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: @ Nick Friskel, Thank you for replying. But I declared the AlarmManger but I didn't include it. My question is using AlarmManager getting message every 5 seconds at the logcat without using service class. I did it with Timer and handler but I didn't get it effiecient.

Comment: I make as you said me but nothing changes :(.

Comment: Does the toast show at all?  Check your alarm by typing in console 'adb shell dumpster alarm' and search your package name, and let me know if the alarm is in there.

Comment: Thanks, It works fine. I was in trouble with Android studio after updating it. Now I checked it, works fine. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are not getting the exact 5 second delay that you need, you will need to use a Handler.  Any type of alarm with a 5 second delay will not work properly because as of Android 5.x basically all repeating alarms are inexact to save battery life.

I have modified your code to use a Handler:

startAlarm();

```
public void startAlarm() {
    final Handler h = new Handler();
    final int delay = 5000; //milliseconds

    h.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            //do something

            Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
            sendBroadcast(alarmIntent);

            h.postDelayed(this, delay);
        }
    }, delay);
}
```

That alarm method will work with your current BroadcastReceiver and do an actual 5 second delay.